# Like button and I keep getting : Reverse for 'like' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']

Tags: python, json, django

i'm making a like button in Django with a JSON code but i keep getting " NoReverseMatch ".In the urls.py and models.py I'm showing all the code, in views.py only the method of the like button and the imports, and in detail.html only the HTML tag's for the like button and the JSON script.
This is what I'm getting in the browser:

```
Reverse for 'like' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/products/7/
    Django Version: 2.2.9
    Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
    Exception Value:    
    Reverse for 'like' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']

Python Version: 3.7.4
```

The models.py in the app "products":

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.urls import reverse

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    pub_date =  models.DateTimeField()
    body = models.TextField()
    url = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/')
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'icon/')
    votes_total = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, unique=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='likes')
    hunter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def summary(self):
        return self.body[:100] + "..."
    def pub_date_pretty(self):
        return self.pub_date.strftime("%b %e %Y")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         #if not self.slug:
            #self.slug = slugify(self.title)

        if not self.slug:
            slug = slugify(self.title)
            while True:
                try:
                    product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
                    if article == self:
                        self.slug = slug
                        break
                    else:
                        slug = slug + '-'
                except:
                    self.slug = slug
                    break
        return super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    @property
    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

The views.py in the app "products":

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Product
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from django.http import HttpResponse
try:
    from django.utils import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json

  .
  .
  .
@login_required(login_url = '/accounts/signup')
@require_POST
def like(request, slug):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        hunter = request.user
        #slug = request.POST.get('slug', None)
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug = slug)

        if product.likes.filter(hunter_id = hunter.id).exists():
            product.likes.remove(hunter)
            message = 'You disliked this'
            product.save()
        else:
            product.likes.add(hunter)
            message = 'You liked this'
            product.save()

    ctx = {'likes_count': product.total_likes, 'message': message}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ctx), content_type='application/json')
```

The urls.py in products app:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('create', views.create, name = 'create'),
    path('<int:product_id>/', views.detail, name = 'detail'),
    path('<int:product_id>/upvote', views.upvote, name = 'upvote'),
    path('user/<int:fk>', views.hunterhunts, name = 'hunterhunts'),
    path('<slug:slug>', views.like, name='like'),
]
```

The HTML file detail.html in the "products" app :

```
<input type="button" id="like" name="{{ product.slug }}" value="Like" />
                    <script>
                    $('#like').click(function() {
                      $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "{% url 'like' %}",
                        data: {
                          'slug': $(this).attr('name'),
                          'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                        },
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(response) {
                          alert(response.message);
                          alert('Product likes count is now ' + response.likes_count);
                        },
                        error: function(rs, e) {
                          alert(rs.responseText);
                        }
                      });
                    });
                  </script>
```

Any idea what should be corrected or added for the like button work.

Please be explicit if you can!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `slug` as an argument in `url: "{% url 'like' %}",`

Like this: `url: "{% url 'like' product.slug %}",`

Comment: Yes that is really helpful it worked, it showed the page, but now when like button is clicked it does pass it through in the data base as "userX" liked the " productX" and the count too doesn't work, any idea why?